# Android App create directory works for most but gives error unable to create directory on sdcard on many

Tags: android, file, save, sd-card, android-sdcard

My application creates a directory name on the phone's sd card and stores a bunch of images in it.  The code works fine for the majority of users, but some are reporting errors saving files.

Here is the code that creates the directory:
    R.string.dir is set to "/appname/"

```
dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ((String) getResources().getText(R.string.dir));

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
    File fDir = new File(dir);
    fDir.mkdirs();
}
else{
    showToast(false,"This Application needs a mounted external storage (sdcard).");
    finish();
}
```

So at this point the directory should be created (it ends up being /mnt/sdcard/appname), or the app finishes.

However when attempting to save the file, some users are reporting this exception:

> Msg: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/appname/file.jpg (No such file or directory)

The code that does the saving:

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/appname/file.jpg");
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream( file );
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos );
}
catch( Exception e ) {
```

Any suggestions?  Could it be that mkdirs() return false (well it would do that if the directory is already created, but then i should be able to write the file in there)?  What would be another reason for it to return false if the sdcard is mounted?  How can I handle this better?

Yes we are using unique file names (appending
System.currentTimeMillis() to the filename).  Also the stream is closed at the end

```
        finally
        {

        if(fos != null) {

        try {

        fos.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        }
```

Comment: please format your source code accordingly when pasting in code. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Have you checked if the card is potentially mounted as read only?

Comment: citizen conn: its my first post, not sure my code was edited already or if I'm supposed to somehow edit it further to fix something. Is there some page with info as to how we're supposed to format code before posting that I missed?

Answer (score 4):

You assume (in the second code sample) that the sdcard paths in all devices is `/mnt/sdcard/`. This is a wrong assumption. you should call [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to get the correct path.

Also, maybe the directory there but not the file, add the following code before opening output stream:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: did you miss the dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory up above in the code?

Comment: @jetson Are you also using the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory call in your file creation code?

Comment: No, this is in he first sample. look at the save file sample: `File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/appname/file.jpg");`

Comment: Perhaps it is futile? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311852/unable-to-write-files-on-sdcard-android    stupid thing how do i do a carriage return without making it post, ie here's the quote "There's nothing legitimately you can do about this -- the OEM is lying to you."  So if we can't really get the 'true' location not much that can be done right?

Comment: Maybe. still be consistent, if you get the path in one way in the first method, get it the same way in the second... Because it might be the OEM fault, but it also might be yours...

Comment: Well I can check if the directory is there, the problem is what can i do if it is not.  Because at that point I don't know where the sdcard is mounted, so I can't create the RIGHT directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the direction that the other posts are going here are some potential problems

1. The names are not the same in first and second method (Or they might be, dont know)
2. Since you are hard coding a name the file might already exist
3. You are not closing the stream
4. You said the string in the resource was set to /appname/ hopefully you mean your applications name, a lot of people might be using the literal appname and file.jpg to store things since that shows up in a lot of tutorials etc.

Modified to take those into account it maybe should look more like this

```
    String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ((String) getResources().getText(R.string.dir));
    File file     = new File(sdCard + "/appname/file.jpg"); // DO YOU WANT YOUR APP NAME OR JUST APPNAME ??? 

    if (file.exists()) // if the jpg already exists --- problems 
       file.delete(); 

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos );
        fos.close(); 
    }
    catch( Exception e ) { ... }
```

Outside of this there can be other potential problems. If the user has the device hooked up to a USB and set as a hard drive the sdcard my not be reachable, the sdcard might be read only, the user might not have an sdcard (which you are checking so cross that one out)

Comment: there's extra code for grabbing the actual 'appname' etc that wasn't included in pasted code...it seems main problem is variation among Android phones/OEMS as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311852/unable-to-write-files-on-sdcard-android  so it appears you have to be creative to get around it for various phones...

Comment: I don't think this is your problem though @jetson  The problem described there is that it returns and internal storage path instead of an external storage path, though that's worth noting for sure.  I have seen the access denied error when the file is present and you try and overwrite it, are you using unique names for the files. Also in the full code are you closing the stream?

Comment: I would also ask those users if they are experiencing this when connected via a USB cable

Comment: Yes we are using unique file names (appending
System.currentTimeMillis() to the filename).  Also the stream is closed at the end

finally
{

if(fos != null) {

try {

fos.close();

}
catch(Exception ex){

ex.printStackTrace();

}

}