# android droid3 different sdcard filesystem?

Tags: android

I developed one year ago an app that just does write a backup on the sdcard root folder.
that worked fine, till i get now complains that the new droid3 does save all files into a folder /sdcard on the sdcard itself.

Now it looks like my app cant handle that. It does say "write successful" but users do not find the file anywhere on their sdcard, also while the app does try to read the backup from the root from the sdcard it does not find anything.

it seems an filesystem behavior that does not stick to the typical android filesystem and so i am stuck as I also dont have a droid3 to test. Any help or advice?

thanks chris

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (root.canWrite()) {
    File gpxfile = new File(root, DATABASE_TABLE + ".myd");
    FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
// later i write for example:
out.write("<data>\n");
```

and here how I read

```
 File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 if (root.canRead()) {
File gpxfile = new File(root, DATABASE_TABLE + ".myd");
FileReader gpxwriter = new FileReader(gpxfile);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(gpxwriter);
while ((dummystr2 = in.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      // read data line by line
    }
```

Comment: Put your read/write code up for a start, the sdcard is not always accessible on the same place per platform, so seeing how you are currently doing it is probably going to save everyone time

Comment: See updated answer, at least it's a starting point

Answer (score 0):

I still think you should put your code up for everyone to take a look at as per the comment.

But if you want to test on real devices here is one place that you can do that [Real Device Testing via DeviceAnywhere](https://www.deviceanywhere.com/product_trial_form.html)

I think you can get three free hours on their service, you probably have to jump through hoops (listen to a sales associate blather on and try to sign you up) but it is one way to test on an actual device without owning that device (and it's live on a 3g/4g network)

There pricing is confusing but definitely expensive,  the free trial should let you get done what you need done I think if you can get them to put a droid 2 up.

Since they don't show a droid 3 (but they might have one and it's just not listed) I bet if you talked to the sales team and said, well interesting but I don't see what I am interested in like the droid 3, they would probably attach one within a couple of days.

**UPDATE:**
So I did some testing on a 2.3.3 device thinking their might be some problem with the root access (thought I read somewhere this was bad form) but it worked fine.

So I did a little more searching, it seems that some devices return mnt/sdcard for the external storage, even though the devices use mnt/sdcard-ext for the actual external SD

From what I have read this means that it *actually* writes to the internal storage, and writes work (if you could call it that) and reads do not. See [Stack Flow Similar Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311852/unable-to-write-files-on-sdcard-android)

Kind of confirmed by some end users [Droid 3 Users - See Page 2](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-3/158498-sd-card-problems-2.html) where they are saying that it creates an internal sdcard partition, though it's unclear if this is typical behavior or results from putting in previously used sdcard, opinions seem to vary but their does seem to be a real issue on devices that have > 8GB internal storage.