# Unable to create directory in External Storage public directory

Tags: android

I am attempting to create a directory and file so that I can store files that I have downloaded from the Internet. However, I am unable to create the directory and file in the external *public* storage. If I write to the external *private* storage (specific storage location for the app) I am perfectly able to do so.

Here is the code:

```
    String storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(storageDirectory);
    File mediaDir = new File(storageDirectory);
    if (!mediaDir.exists()) {
        System.out.println(mediaDir.mkdirs());
        System.out.println(mediaDir.isDirectory());
    }
    File mediaFile = new File(storageDirectory, "boga.jpg");
    try {
        mediaFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above code results in:

> 09-13 05:33:45.258    5867-5867/? I/System.out﹕ /storage/0CED-0F09/Pictures

09-13 05:33:45.260    5867-5867/? I/System.out﹕ false

09-13 05:33:45.260    5867-5867/? I/System.out﹕ false

With an IOException (No such file or directory):

> 09-13 05:33:45.260    5867-5867/? W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> 09-13 05:33:45.260    5867-5867/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
>
> 09-13 05:33:45.260    5867-5867/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.terabyte.tut1app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)

And this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: not sure this will be of any help, but why don't you store in mediaDir the result of Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory directly? Instead of getting the path and then recreating a file?

Comment: @unbekant - that was just for the sake of printing out the path.

Comment: @Rami i think your memory card not mounted.. are you trying it when connected to usb in laptop or computer.

Comment: @sourabhbans - This is with an emulated android device. The SD card is mounted and shows correctly within the Android device (I can see how much is stored, folders, etc.).

Comment: Can you see this directory `/storage/0CED-0F09/` in the emulator?

Comment: @shhp - no, I see the following: http://i.imgur.com/bTu2qn3.png and in the device manager: http://i.imgur.com/KwY2gao.png

Comment: It seems the name of the directory is changing. Can you try your app in a real device?

Comment: @shhp I executed the app on a real device and I was able to write the file successfully. However, the file/directory does not appear in the Internal storage or the external. This is the path I created: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/test


Even after unplugging and plugging the device in again I cannot locate the folder. The question still remains though, why am I unable to write to external storage using the emulator?

Comment: From the screen capture of the device manager it seems that there is no group write permission to the `storage` directory.  Maybe a problem of emulated sdcard setup.

Comment: @headuck - Do you know how this could be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I am fully capable of writing to the external storage directory on a real smartphone device (Huawei P8 api level 21, Version 5.0). But not to the emulator's external storage, even though the storage is fully available and can be browsed from within the emulator.

This also helped me in figuring out issues with the external storage on a real device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311955/5330055

I have no longer urgently require a solution on this, but it would be nice to know what is wrong with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually nothing wrong with emulator.**

Probably device you have used on emulator were on android equal or higher than version 6.0

In 6.0 and higher versions you need to request write permission at runtime. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

*in your smartphone it worked because it was on android 5.0*

if this help someone I will glad.